# Ask minimal sufficient statistics for double-exponential distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a random sample from double-exponential $(\mu, 1), \mu \in \mathcal{R}$, i.e., the joint pdf of $X$ is

$$f_\mu (x)= \frac{1}{2^n} \exp(-\Sigma_{i=1}^n |x_i-\mu|)$$

Consider $\mathcal{F}_0=\{f_0,f_1,...,f_n \}$, where each $f_j$ is the pdf with $\mu=j,j=,1,...,n$. By Theorem 6.6.5a in Casella and Berger's statistical inference textbook, a minimal sufficient statistics for $\mathcal{F}_0$ is

$$T=(\exp(\Sigma_{i=1}^n |X_i|-   \Sigma_{i=1}^n |X_i-j|),j=1,...,n)$$ which is equivalent to

$$U=(\Sigma_{i=1}^n |X_i|-   \Sigma_{i=1}^n |X_i-j|,j=1,...,n)$$

We can further show that $U$ is equivalent to $S$, the set of order  statistics. Since $S$ is sufficient, by Theorem 6.6.5b, $S, U$ and $T$ are all minimal sufficient.

I need the help that how I can justify the step "$U$ is equivalent to $S$, the set of order  statistics."